# I try to render elements from an array from firestore but nothing happens?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend

```
        import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {collection, getDocs, doc} from "firebase/firestore"
import {db} from "../firebaseConfig/firebase"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
const Cards = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const productsCollection = collection(db, "zproducts");

  const categoria = useParams()

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const data = await getDocs(productsCollection);
    if(categoria.category){
    const dataCategory = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
    setProducts(dataCategory.filter(i=> i.category === categoria.category))
      console.log(products)
    }else {

      setProducts(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  }
}


  useEffect(()=>{

    getProducts()

  },[categoria.category])

 

    return (
  
      <>
  
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
  
        {products.map((product) => (
  
          <Card className="card" key={product.id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
  
            <Card.Img variant="top" className="cardImg" src={product.imgProduct} />
  
            <Card.Body>
  
              <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
  
          
  
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-around">
  
              <Link  variant="primary" className="btn btn-dark boton btnDetalles" to={`/Item/${product.id}`}>Ver Detalles</Link>
  
              </div>
  
            </Card.Body>
  
          </Card>
  
        ))}
  
        </div>
  
      </>
  
    );
  
  }

export default Cards;
```

Ok so when I try to create a p tag rendering product.name it does not render, it should render next to the boostrap card, but for some reason nothing happens.

[When I do a console log the array from firestore does appear, but if I do for example console.log(products.name) I get undefined as a result on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiumH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u forgot that return in map:

```js
{products.map((product) => {
   return <div key={product.id}>
               <p>{product.name}</p>
              </div>
    })}
```

also u can do:

```js
{products.map((product) => (
    <div key={product.id}>
       <p>{product.name}</p>
     </div>
 ))}
```

Comment: I know it was a syntax error, thank you so much you saved me!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `Firestore` `getDocs()` results does not have the `.map` method. I ran into the same issue and end up using the `.forEach` method:

**Instead of this:**

```
const data = await getDocs (productsCollection)
setProducts(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(),id:doc.id})))
```

**Use this:**

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs (productsCollection)

let data = [];

querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
  data.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
});

setProducts(data);
```

**OLD ANSWER**

(This is still relevant for people who set an `undefined` key on a `React` .map iterator that outputting DOM.)

Based on your screenshot, where it seems there is no `id` property set in any of your objects. If there is no `id`, then this section may have rendering issues since your `key` is `undefined`.

Comment: it does have an id, which is provided by firestore from what I know, this is what the array shows when I expand it:
 0: 
category: 
"manga"
description: 
"Coleccion Dragon Ball Super vol 1 al 9"
id: 
"Dxa7t0oBd6iMw3pPEqc6"
imgProduct: 
"https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/HHQAAOSwjl9hnT2u/s-l1600.jpg"
name: 
"Manga Dragon ball Super"
stock: 
23
[[Prototype]]: 
Object

Comment: Please see the revised answer.